# Gagliardo-Nirenberg inequality for fractional Sobolev spaces

Tags: integral-inequality, fractional-sobolev-spaces

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gagliardo%E2%80%93Nirenberg_interpolation_inequality) states two versions of the Gagliardo-Nirenberg inequality for nonfractional Sobolev spaces. I'm interested in generalizations to fractional (Slobodeckij) Sobolev spaces.

Such a generalization of the version for functions on $\mathbb{R}^n$ can be found e.g. [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1611.00734.pdf).

Unfortunately, I don't find such a generalization of the version for functions defined on a bounded Lipschitz domain $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$. I'm pretty sure that the inequality still holds if one replaces the terms $\|D^j u\|_{L^p}$ and $\|D^m u\|_{L^r}$ by the corresponding Gagliardo semi-norms.

Does anyone know an article/book where such a generalization can be found?

Comment: I could solve my original problem (that I didn't mention here) without using the Gagliardo-Nirenberg inequality for functions defined on bounded Lipschitz domains. I combined the Gagliardo-Nirenberg inequality for functions on $\mathbb{R}^n$ with Lemma 5.1 and Lemma 5.3 from [Hitchhiker's guide](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1104.4345.pdf).

Comment: If it helps someone: The Gagliardo-Nirenberg inequality for functions defined on bounded Lipschitz domains $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ follows from the version for functions on $\mathbb{R}^n$ and Theorem 5.4 from [Hitchhiker's guide](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1104.4345.pdf). Only the following must be taken into account here: From the proof of Theorem 5.4, it is clear that the extension $\tilde u$ satisfies not only $\|\tilde u\|_{W^{s,p}(\mathbb{R}^n)} \leq C \|u\|_{W^{s,p}(\Omega)}$ but also $\|\tilde u\|_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)} \leq C_2 \|u\|_{L^2(\Omega)}$.

Comment: But, from your second comment, we don't conclude that the Gagliardo-Nirenberg Inequality holds over bounded domains. Right?

Comment: You can conclude that it holds for bounded Lipschitz domains.

Comment: What Gagliardo-Nirenberg inequality in $\mathbb{R}^n$ are you considering? $(1.1)$ [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1611.00734.pdf)? And where to use your suggestion in order to obtain  Gagliardo-Nirenberg inequality in bounded Lipschitz domains?

Comment: Yes and then just use Theorem 5.4 of Hitchhiker's guide.

Comment: If you can give more details I would appreciate it, as I can't see how to use Theorem $5.4$ to complete the inequality. I suggest adding as an answer, it would help the community a lot, since there are few materials with this type of content (Gagliardo-Nirenberg inequality for fractional Sobolev spaces on bounded domains).

Answer (score 1):

It is straightforward. You have $u$ defined on $\Omega$ and then the extension $\tilde u$ defined on $\mathbb{R}^n$. Now the Gagliardo semi-norm of $u$ can be estimated trivially by the Gagliardo semi-norm of $\tilde u$ (just because it's an extension). Since $\tilde u$ is defined on $\mathbb{R}^n$ you can now use the Gagliardo-Nirenberg inequality for such functions. Finally, use Theorem 5.4 of Hitchhiker's guide to bound the appearing norms of $\tilde u$ by norms of $u$.